# A way to contact people after they have put 'question on hold'?

Tags: feature-request

I have been thinking about this for a long time- should there not be a better way to talk to a mod/user *after they have put your question on hold*?

When a question is not up-to-the-mark moderators/users usually put it on hold (and they should!). But. they *mostly* give a very vague explanation, i.e. a random quote from the Stack Overflow help page. The reason for this might be they don't have all the time in the world. True, but what if the explanation is **so** vague, a novice (or anyone for that matter) does not understand **why** exactly their question was taken down? Even if the novice is *legitimately* wrong, they might think they were right, because of the vague explanation.

Sometimes, mods forget they ever put a question on hold (even after changes were made)! Believe me, I have had a few experiences. So, I think there should be a way for the person in question, to contact that *specific* mod/user who took their post down and understand what went wrong.

Of course, the Stack Overflow help page says "flag any content and a moderator will come to you!" (Or something like that). We all know that would not work in this case. And how can I forget the **reopen review queue**? Seriously, how many people with above 3k reputation exist, *and* look at that list? Another way was, "leave a comment and the user will get back to you!". I tried it, did not work. Then I thought. if *I* was the user, would I respond to a random comment on (one of my, oh so many) Posts?* So, comments *might* work but, it is quite a moon-shot.

Now, why would a user listen to a request for re-evaluation then? Answer is: If it is a different stream of messages (separate from comments) then at the least they would *read* **some** *of them*, because it won't be like spam to them!

*I assume people who put questions on hold are regular users of Stack Overflow and contribute (question and answers) a whole lot to the community.

Comment: You can already ping them in comments on your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The purpose of our queues and flagging systems is to allow anyone who can see it to handle the issue; not just the specific people who conducted the action.  Also; you're more likely to get an unbiased response from someone other than the person who closed your question, since you'd be asking someone to reverse a decision they made (that's another reason why we have queues and flagging).

Comment: yes i know.. i have written about that

Comment: @GeorgeStocker good point about the bias

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ note that [you *can't* ping a close voter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/2952320) (unless he/she commented as well, is a moderator or used a dupehammer)

Comment: `And how can I forget the reopen review queue? Seriously, how many people with above 3k reputation exist, and look at that list? `  Quite a few.  Of all queues, that is usually the one that is empty, or at least has the fewest posts.

Comment: @Glorfindel Ah, good to know. I'm a gold badge holder and were pinged a number of times.

Comment: @psubsee2003 sorry, but i usually see it bursting

Comment: @Rainbowteddycoderguy no,  The close vote queue is bursting.  The reopen queue is never full.

Comment: @psubsee2003 hmm.. i have had a different experience

Comment: Thank you everyone for looking at this. I am rather gratified(no sarcasm intended)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have been thinking about this for a long time- should there not be a better way to talk to a mod/user after they have put your question on hold?

This is a simple answer - **No**.

While it would be nice if there was a customized comment for every single on-hold question explaining exactly what is wrong, reviewers simply do not have the bandwidth to discuss the close decisions personally with everyone.  And when you add it the issue of users getting angry and offended that someone dared close their question, allowing a direct line of communication would permit those reviewers/close voters to get harassed by the author of any question that got closed.  It would simply discourage users from closing questions, and we don't want that.

> Sometimes, mods forget they ever put a question on hold(even after changes were made)! Believe me, I have had a few experiences. So, I think there should be a way for the person in question, to contact that specific mod/user who took their post down and understand what went wrong.

It is not common for users to reopen questions that they themselves closed.  But that is why we have the reopen queue.  I think [George Stocker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326176/a-way-to-contact-people-after-they-have-put-question-on-hold#comment357478_326176) also brings up a very good point in his comment, *"you're more likely to get an unbiased response from someone other than the person who closed your question, since you'd be asking someone to reverse a decision they made"*.

> And how can I forget the reopen review queue? Seriously, how many people with above 3k reputation exist, and look at that list?

Actually, quite a few.  It is frequently one of the more empty review queues on the site.  Posts in the reopen queue tend to get reviewed fairly quickly, especially when compared to some of the others (like the close vote queue).

A personal observation, however, is that that once closed, the expected level of quality of a post by the reviewers is much higher than it would have been if it was asked correctly the first time.  It is not uncommon for a below average but clear post to remain open but once closed, it really needs to be a good question to get reopened.

Here's a screen shot from just a few minutes ago of the review queues.

> [image]

---

And to jump back to what I think is a good point to discuss

> ...but what if the explanation is so vague, a novice(or anyone for that matter) does not understand why exactly their question was taken down? Even if the novice is legitimately wrong, they might think they were right, because of the vague explanation.

That is what chat and meta are for.  While you do need 20 rep to participate in chat, you can ask questions about your own post on meta without the usual 5 rep restriction.

The trick, however, is coming to meta with a constructive attitude.  The users who come and start ranting and demanding often see their meta question downvoted and their Stack Overflow question even more heavily downvoted, the ones that come with a constructive attitude and a willingness to learn will usually get a decent explanation of the likely reasons (although the extra attention you draw to the post may still lead to it getting downvoted more than it would have had you not asked originally).

But just be sure to learn from what you are told.  The meta community is much smaller and users will tend to remember you.  If you run to meta for every post you ask, you are more than likely to annoy people, especially if you aren't taking the advice you were given in a previous question.

Comment: Hi, I think I came across as a person ranting for his SO question to be reopened. I don't know if you will believe me but, I am not complaining. I wanted a friendly discussion and I got one! I now know that I was wrong. Good move by MSO to not decrease rep in SO because of downvotes in MSO, as MSO is more of a discussion site.

Comment: @Rainbowteddycoderguy never said you were.  I was just drawing the line between "how to get real help on meta" and "how to get your question downvoted quickly".  It is not uncommon for people to come and rant and demand on meta though.  But when you come here and say "My question (link) was closed as <insert close reason>.  But I don't understand what that means and how it applies to my question", you will find more help

Comment: Yes the rant was evident :P